# navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') doesn't work from inside a HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

### Calling navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')  from inside a HOC doesn't open the drawer menu

```
I have written a higher order component which returns a screen with header  for drawer navigator.
```

#### Header

```
const Header = (props)=>{

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"red",justifyContent:"center"}}>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => {
                        props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
                        if (props.navigation.state.index === 0) {
                            props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
                        } else {
                            props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')
                        }
                    }}>
                        <View >
                            <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:"white"}}>{"Menu"}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
    );
}
```

#### HOC

```
 const createCompWithHeader = (Comp)=>{

    return (props)=>{
        return (

            <View style={{flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
                <Header {...props}/>
                <View style={{flex:9}}>
                    <Comp {...props}/>
                </View>      
            </View>
        );
    }
    }
```

#### Drawer Navigator

```
const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
        Home: {
        screen: createCompWithHeader(MyHomeScreen),
    },
    Notifications: {
        screen: createCompWithHeader(MyNotificationsScreen),
    },

});
```

#### Components(Screens)

```
class MyHomeScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Home'
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button 
                    onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} 
                    title={"Open menu"}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
                    title="Go to notifications"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Notifications'
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            <Button 
                onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} 
                title={"Open Menu"}
            />
            <Button
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
                title="Go home"
            /></View>
        );
    }
}
```

---

#### Current Behavior

- when I click on the button in header(props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')), the drawer menu doesn't open
- When I click on the button inside the component, menu opens

#### Expected Behavior

- On click of the button in the header, menu should open.

#### How to reproduce

- Expo Url : [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/rkdx7mkhz)

#### Environment

| react-navigation |1.5.8

| react-native     |0.55.2

Answer (score 3):

After 2.0 release, rather than opening a drawer with `navigation.navigate(‘DrawerOpen’)`, you can now call `navigation.openDrawer()`.

Other methods are `closeDrawer()` and `toggleDrawer()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your snack expo and the problem lies in this snippet

```
 if (props.navigation.state.index === 0) {
                            props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
                        } else {
                            props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose')
                        }
```

The navigation does not add an index to the state, therefore it's value remains undefined

So what you are doing is , *Opening and Closing the drawer yourself*

Therefore remove this snippet to see it work.

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured that out :) .  Thank you.